# Телеграмм Бот + MySQL (проблема с выводом)

Tags: python, mysql, python-telegram-bot

Создал телеграмм бота, задача у него проста, выводить данные по имени игрока которое было введено пользователем, также есть функция вывода всех игроков.
Но есть проблема, что выводятся только названия столбцов, я уже несколько раз все проверил, не понимаю в чем ошибка. Буду очень благодарен за помощь

[первый скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvlOG.png)

[второй скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a87fI.png)

Пробовал многое, вносил в цикл try: и except: переделывал сам код, где должен быть вывод информации, делал разные конструкции. Решил оставить наиболее популрную и станртную конструкцию, которая везде участвует, но у меня не работает. Самое что интересное, в телеграмме бот выводит только 'name', хотя в самом коде если сделать print то все выводится корректно

'''
def infa(message):

```
try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host='',
        port=3306,
        user='',
        password='',
        database='gs74925',
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )
    print("successfully connected...")
    print("#" * 20)
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT name, password, email FROM accounts")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Name          Password         Email")

            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id,row )
                print(row)
    finally:
        connection.close()

except Exception as ex:
    print("Connection refused...")
    print(ex)
```

'''
Вот часть кода которая отвечает за высылание всей информации из таблицы аккаунты (ну не всей только имя, пароль и почту) База данных в phpmyadmin соеденение устанавливается корректно, проблема только с выводом. Получается если написать  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,row ) и print(row) по идее должно вывести что в телеграмме что в консоли одно и тоже, но в телеграмме выводится просто название столбца без наполнения просто 'name'. При этом в консоли выводится все верно, и даже если отслеживать вывод в тг и в консоли они идут идентично, но почему то телеграмм больше 'name' не хочет выводить (скрин прикрепил только с именами где выводится в консоли, а так почта, пароль все тоже работает)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def infa(message):
    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(
            host='',
            port=3306,
            user='',
            password='',
            database='gs74925',
            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
        print("successfully connected...")
        print("#" * 20)
        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("SELECT name, password, email FROM accounts")
                message_text = "Name          Password         Email\n"
                
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
                for row in rows:
                    message_text += f"{row['name']}          {row['password']}         {row['email']}\n"
                
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_text)
                
                for row in rows:
                    print(row['name'], row['password'], row['email'])
        finally:
            connection.close()

    except Exception as ex:
        print("Connection refused...")
        print(ex)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, код очень хороший и понятный, вы дали суперский шаблон для дальнейшего развития бота